# Mootools 1.2.5 Element.setStyle / Morph

Tags: mootools, mootools1.2

I recently made a Mootols script for my website. Using Fx.Morph, I succesfully created the effects I was aiming for. However, the script fails in Internet Explorer 7 and 8 (works fine in 9, didn't not bother to check IE6). I am using mootools 1.2.5.

Digging up the problem, I could figure out the following

- All my problems are coming from Fx.Morph, who calls setStyle with invalid values
- Somehow, while morphing height of an element from 0px to 160px, setStyle is called with a negative value (such as -3px) <---- this is where IE throws an error

For now, I "patched" the error by doing the following in the setStyle function of the Mootools core:

```
if((Browser.Engine.trident && value[0] == '-' && (property == 'height' || property == 'width')) || value[0] == 'N')
    value='0px';
```

Anyone has some more info on this issue or experienced a similar problem?

Comment: please share the morph code or better yet, go to www.jsfiddle.net and build a working example that breaks. out of experience, IE throws a wobbly if it gets the wrong kind of value for the wrong property, something you can reliably check if you say, do `element.setStyle("scroll", "none");` which works on other browsers. having a negative height in IE sounds like a bad thing to do. FYI, this has also been a problem in jquery - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5588 - build the test case and i will see what i can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Morph doesn't care if it is about to call setStyle with invalid property/value combo and setStyle doesn't either care if it is about to set an invalid value for a specified property.

With this in mind, my problem came from the effect I was using. I was using something like "Bounce.easeIn" with an element that had to morph height from 0px to 160px. Morph would then call setStyle with negative values.

In my case, setting the effect to "linear" made it works like expected.

In my opinion, Morph should be "aware" of what it is about to do and prevent calling setStyle with invalid values. Element.setStyle should also throw an error when he is called with impossible property / value instead of letting browser crash/handle the problem. I'll see if this has been fixed in 1.3 and open a ticket if not.

Comment: not going to happen. this implies having a per-browser valid regex of every possible value every possible attribute you pass it can have. the framework should not be the one that fool proofs the browser, it's just an API and it is ultimately the web developer's responsibility to only pass ones that are valid and make sense.

Comment: I understand your point, concerning setStyle. However, having a box with negative dimension is invalid as per the W3C. Morph shouldn't be trying to create an invalid box.

I understand IE is the only one crashing in this scenario, while other browsers I tested simply ignores this. I also had another issue today where i was sending "NaNpx" to setStyle. No browser complained except IE. In my opinion, every browser should have crashed, since this is obviously a major error.

Comment: the problem is with an elastic transition that goes beyond the target number and comes back, really. however, transitions are universal, they transition between numbers and the application of that transition into morphing the height is secondary. I would simply go, if `transition: Browser.Engine.trident && Browser.version < 9 ? somethingelse : bouncin,` - btw check browser object if that is lowercase or cap V

Comment: you can also add a try / catch block (use $try if IE)